# In ss -s, what is the kernel counter actually counting?

Tags: linux, sockets, memory-management, linux-kernel, ss

While troubleshooting a problem on an OEL 7 server (3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64), I ran the command

```
sudo ss -s
```

Which gave me the output of:

```
Total: 601 (kernel 1071)
TCP:   8 (estab 2, closed 0, orphaned 0, synrecv 0, timewait 0/0), ports 0

Transport Total     IP        IPv6
        1071     -         -
RAW        2         0         2
UDP        6         4         2
TCP        8         5         3
INET       16        9         7
FRAG       0         0         0
```

Doing an `ss -a | wc -l` came back with 225 entries.

It leads me to the question, what is `kernel 1071` actually counting? 
Looking through the various man pages did not provide an answer.
Using *`strace`*, I can see where *`ss`* reads:

```
/proc/net/sockstat
/proc/net/sockstat6
/proc/net/snmp
/proc/slabinfo
```

Looking through those files and the docs, it looks like the value is coming from *`/proc/slabinfo`*.
Grepping through *`/proc/slabinfo`* for 1071 came back with one entry:

```
sock_inode_cache    1071   1071    640   51    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     21     21      0
```

Looking through the files and docs on `sock_inode_cache` has not helped so far. I am hoping someone here knows what the kernel counter is actually counting, or can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is kernel 1071 actually counting?

`sock_inode_cache` represents Linux kernel [Slab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slab_allocation) statistics. It shows how many socket inodes (active objects) are there.

[`struct socket_alloc`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.161/source/include/net/sock.h#L1345) corresponds to the `sock_inode_cache` slab cache and contains the `struct socket` and `struct inode`, so it is connected to [VFS](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/vfs.txt).

Comment: Thank you very much, now it makes a lot more sense